# Sound plays when I click on an object

Tags: lua, roblox

I can't get a sound to play when I click the part.

How can I integrate the sound code into the following code?

```
local ClickDetector = script.Parent.ClickDetector

ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.SurfaceLight1.Enabled = not script.Parent.SurfaceLight1.Enabled
end)

ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.SurfaceLight2.Enabled = not script.Parent.SurfaceLight2.Enabled
end)

ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.SurfaceLight3.Enabled = not script.Parent.SurfaceLight3.Enabled
end)

ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.SurfaceLight4.Enabled = not script.Parent.SurfaceLight4.Enabled
end)
```

Comment: Heyo Russian-Dev, if you're looking for a place to start, have you looked at any of the [code samples or tutorials](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/sounds-and-music) for [Sound objects](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Sound) yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
local function onMouseClick(Player)
    if not Player.PlayerGui:findFirstChild("ClickAudio") then 
        local ls = Instance.new("Sound")
        local length = 1 -- How long the sound plays before removed.

        ls.SoundId = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=" -- Audio id here.
        ls.Name = "ClickAudio"
        ls.Volume = 0.5 -- You can set the volume (Suggestion: keep it below 1)
        ls.Pitch = 1 -- This is the pitch of the sound
        ls.Parent = Player.PlayerGui
        ls:Play()

        game:GetService("Debris"):AddItem(ls, length)
    end
end
script.Parent.MouseClick:connect(onMouseClick)
```

You would have to change the SoundId = "" and paste in the link of the sound you want to play, I hope this answered your question!

Answer (score 0):

I see you're an [RLua](https://github.com/whitequark/rlua) developer. Could you make a local of the sound?

By the way, a client-side script would look like this:

```
local Sound = workspace.Sound
 ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
        Sound:Play()
    end)
```

Well, you can make a remote that is fired when the button is clicked to make it server-side (everyone hears it). Make a remote, add a *script* (not local) anywhere and the code should be like:

```
local Sound = workspace.Sound
local RemoteEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.PlaySound
RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
Sound:Play() -- Yes, it's all LOL
end)
```

I forgot to tell that all your code is client-side, and other players won't see the lights changing, but... if your game has too many customizable remotes (like you make a remote that fires kill for admin, then it can be abused by hackers), so it's not the best - I am not going to lie. A game can't have a single hack.

Comment: I found a way on how to make the sound play but how can the lights and sound be server-side?
Edit: My code is in a script, not LocalScript.

Comment: u gotta use remote events that the way